# yarn add @metaplex-foundation/js failing

Tags: git, yarnpkg

I have been trying to run "yarn add @metaplex-foundation/js" for a project I am working on which fails with

```
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/Bundlr-Network/avsc
Directory: /Users/.../.../currentrepo
Output:
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 140.82.112.3]: errno=Operation timed out
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

This is the only package I cannot install but `yarn add` works for any other library I try to install with no problem.

One solution I tried was redoing my ssh key which did not help.

I have found similar problems but none with only one package not installing let alone this package specifically.

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what's wrong: Git reached out to `https://github.com/Bundlr-Network/avsc` (via libcurl) and got dead silence and eventually gave up. Probably your network connection was down; try again later. If it stays out all the time, contact your IT support guys and find out why access to github is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

> One solution I tried was redoing my ssh key which did not help.

`yarn` tries to contact GitHub through HTTPS, so an SSH key would not help here, and would be ignored.

If the same `yarn add` succeeds in installing other libraries through `https://github.com/...`, except for this one, then it points to an issue with this specific library (as opposed to a general network issue).

This is [`Bundlr-Network/avsc`](https://github.com/Bundlr-Network/avsc), last updated 4 years ago, and which is ultimately forked from the more up-to-date [`mtth/avsc`](https://github.com/mtth/avsc).
It possibly uses the more recent version of `avsc`.

---

If you need Git to use SSH instead of HTTPS in your project, you can try:

```
git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf https://github.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

.gitconfig file was not set up properly to do shh instead of http.

vim ~./gitconfig

Then make necessary edits to file

Comment: What "necessary edit" did you do? I have edited my own answer to include such an edit.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).